# LibreOffice Writer: spell checking of camel-case words

Tags: libreoffice, spell-check, libreoffice-writer

I'm writing a software documentation using LibreOffice Writer. I often refer to class or function names in this documentation. For example *ChessBoard* or *getCell*. These are all underscored with red wavy lines and I'm getting a bit annoyed about it.

Is there an option or add-on that I can turn on so LO would recognize that a capital letter in the middle of the word is a clue that it is a camel-case expression so it should be spell-checked part by part, not all at once?

Comment: Since it comes mainly from _class functions_ you may try either to write all them starting with a capital letter and un-check the corresponding option (it should be possible to ignore the spell-check on the proper name...),  either to create a [user defined dictionary](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Writing_Aids#User-defined_dictionaries) with all the words from your programs (in an automatic way, with awk or each other parser...) either to add manually the annoying ones to the user defined dictionary. Let me know if something works for you.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that an option or an add-on exists for the spell-checking of
camel-case words, but I can offer the following workaround.

The idea is to encode the documentation file in Unicode (such as UTF-8)
and to insert a
[Zero-width joiner character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner)
between the words. This weird character is defined as:

> The zero-width joiner (ZWJ) is a non-printing character used in the computerized typesetting of some complex scripts such as the Arabic script or any Indic script. When placed between two characters that would otherwise not be connected, a ZWJ causes them to be printed in their connected forms.
>
> The character's code point is U+200D ZERO WIDTH JOINER (HTML `&#8205; &zwj;`).

The insertion of the character can easily be done by a simple regex substitution.  It can also be inserted by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> +200D.

If this idea works, each word will be separately spell-checked,
but the two words will always be printed as attached with
no space or line-break in-between.
However, I don't use LibreOffice Writer and cannot test the idea.

*Edit by fixer1234: I tested this in LO Writer v6.0 and can confirm that it works.  Also, the capitalized camelcase component words are not viewed by LO as capitalization errors (the capitalization is ignored).*

For more information about such characters, see the article
[The Beauty of Unicode: Zero-Width Characters](https://www.ptiglobal.com/2018/04/26/the-beauty-of-unicode-zero-width-characters/).

Comment: @fixer1234: I don't know about Writer, but these wouldn't cause an error in Microsoft Office. In fact, while researching before writing this answer I only found that Writer has heuristics for detecting when mid-sentence upper-case is *missing*, where the example was "president Obama" that should be "President Obama".

Comment: By George, you're right.  At least with the standard checkers for LibreOffice, it ignores capitalization of mid-sentence words.  Which means that the ZWJ pretty much does what the OP wants (and I confirmed that it works in LO).

Comment: This has some rather significant downsides, though - with a ZWJ in the middle, you won't be able to search for the whole string in the document, and if you try to copy-paste to somewhere else, the ZWJ will be copied too. Seems like a pretty big problem for documentation.

Comment: @InquisitiveLurker: Just remember to always do regex search for camel-case words.

Answer (score 1):

Spelling and grammar checkers are designed to detect the mistakes people make.  Camelcase is an intentional mistake.  There is no dictionary of correct camelcase words, any recognition must be via pattern.  Unfortunately, the camelcase pattern is exactly the kind of error that English language checkers look for: multiple words missing a space between them and a capitalized word in the middle of a sentence that isn't a proper noun.

There isn't a way to distinguish between intentional camelcase and the kinds of errors the checkers are designed to catch.  The only way to deal with it is to ignore anything with that pattern, which means the checker will miss some actual errors.  LibreOffice doesn't have a native provision to ignore just the camelcase pattern.  They have a [repository of extensions](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/extensions), but there are none for adding camelcase capability.  If you don't want to see the wavy line, you need to disable checking in general.

[word 2010 spell checker chokes on Camel Case](https://superuser.com/q/372785/364367) was asked here many years ago about Word.  An online search didn't find any evidence that the situation has changed for Word, either.

This issue has especially been a problem with program documentation because that's where camelcase is common in a normal document.  Some enterprising programmers have found ways to modify spell checkers to handle camelcase.  For example, in this answer on Stack Overflow, [Using ispell/aspell to spell check camelcased words](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5111709/6278788), someone figured out how to modify the Ispell spelling checker.  If you have some programming skill, you could replicate that.

I understand that there are some software development environments, like WebStorm for JavaScript and Visual Studio Code, that may contain a provision for handling camelcase, but that probably isn't a great way to work on normal documents.

Aside from a few references like that, I couldn't find any off-the-shelf spell checker that would enable you to at least disable spell checking while you work and then check everything with a separate program that ignores camelcase.  That leaves just disabling checking while you work so you're not bothered by the wavy lines, then checking the whole document, camelcase and all.